# Using Python, get the day of the current month as an integer

Tags: python, date

I need to write a method that returns the day of the month as an integer. For example, if it's Feb 8th 2011, I want to have method like this:

```
>>> day = get_day_of_month()
```

where day would be given the integer value 8

Comment: I find it odd when people say: `What have you tried, and how doesn't it work?` when they seem to answer about almost any other question in which they should be asking this. At least in this case the OP did try something. What about the other answers in which people ask for a solution and they are presented with an answer immediately (perhaps answered for rep?)

Comment: Google `python get day of month` gives second search result as `http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html` where the `datetime` class is described. Shouldn't need to harness SO for this kind of questions. Thanks

Comment: @A A: One can only give so many freebies before it gets annoying. As I understand it, SO is not a `Here's what I want, give me some code.` site, no matter how often that actually happens.

Comment: Well @eat, if you Google `python get day of month`, this is the top result. I wanted a SO answer to be top, because I know they can give a concise code snippet instead of having to dig through documentation and irrelevant examples to find what I need.

Comment: @JamEngulfer, that's exactly why I like StackOverflow, too!  Mucking through the documentation gives me so many more questions.  And the answer to this question is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.today().day
```

Answer (score 11):

```
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.now()
today.day # this is a integer
```

Answer (score 4):

Or the "old school" (lower overhead, if it matters) method...

```
import time 
time.localtime(time.time())[2]
```

time.localtime() returns a tuple containing all of the elements of a timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the [answer by programmersbook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4934820/832230). It uses [**`datetime.date`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) rather than `datetime.datetime`.

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.date.today().day
8
```